# Is it correct to have nested random effects when you have multiple questions per item?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, random-effects-model, nested-data

Let's imagine a study where people study 50 images. After each image they get get 5 true/false questions about the image (different questions for each image; e.g., was there a tree in the image you just saw).

The DV is accuracy on these questions. The predictor is study time (within subjects, they see half of the images for five seconds, half for ten seconds). Images can appear in either level, counterbalanced across participants. This example is just made up to get to my question...

Does it make sense to have a random effects structure with question nested within image?

Edit: Changed predictor in the example.

Comment: Do all people get the same images?  Is question order randomized?  Do all subjects get the same five questions for each image?

Comment: Everyone gets the same images, but they can appear in either level of the predictor (I've updated the question to say this). Order is randomized. All subjects get the same questions for each image.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are different questions for each image, this would meet the definition of nested random effects, provided that each question belongs to one and only one image. Since all subjects see all images, then `subject` is crossed with `image` (and `question`). Since the research question concerns study time, one approach using a mixed model would be:

```
accuracy ~ study_time + (1|subject) + (1|image/question)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not, please let us know why. Also, if you haven't already, please consider upvoting it.